# Foreign key error 150 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I know there are already a lot of such questions, but my tables happen to be much simpler and both the columns are indexed. So hopefully this won't get downvoted. :)

Here's the first table:

```
create table users (
    user_num int primary key auto_increment,
    first_name varchar(50),
    last_name varchar(50),
    date_of_birth date,
    email varchar(100),
    password varchar(50),
    note_data longtext
);
```

And here's the second, which is throwing the error:

```
create table documents
(
    doc_num int primary key auto_increment,
    user_num int,
    doc_data longtext,
    note_data longtext,
    index(user_num),
    foreign key (user_num) references users.user_num on delete cascade
);
```

Here I'm creating an index on user_num in the documents table while referencing the key, and the referenced column is already indexed, being a primary key. What is causing the error, then?

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is not correct. The columns referenced must be in `()`

```
create table documents
(
    doc_num int primary key auto_increment,
    user_num int,
    doc_data longtext,
    note_data longtext,
    foreign key (user_num) references users (user_num) on delete cascade
) engine = InnoDB;
```

Comment: This is it! Thank you for spotting this. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that ENGINE=InnoDB or ENGINE=MyISAM. Also make sure that  primary key column(s) in the parent table and the Foreign Key column(s) must be the same data type.

Try this:

```
create table documents
(
    doc_num int primary key auto_increment,
    user_num int,
    doc_data longtext,
    note_data longtext,
    foreign key (user_num) references users (user_num) on delete cascade
) engine = InnoDB;
```

Comment: The engine for the first table in InnoDB, which I believe is the default since I didn't specify anything while creating the table. The same goes for the second table, which if created, should have InnoDB as its engine. As for column types, you can see that everything is in order.